# Intersect two dataframes in Pandas with respect to first dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to intersect two Pandas dataframes (1 and 2) based on two columns (A and B) present in both dataframes. However, I would like to return a dataframe that only has data with respect to the data in the first dataframe, omitting anything that is not found in the second dataframe.

So for example:

```
Dataframe 1: 
A | B | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |
----------------------------------
1 | 2 | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |
1 | 3 | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |
1 | 5 | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |

Dataframe 2: 
A | B | Extra | Columns | In | 2 |
----------------------------------
1 | 3 | Extra | Columns | In | 2 |
1 | 4 | Extra | Columns | In | 2 |
1 | 5 | Extra | Columns | In | 2 |
```

should return:

```
A | B | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |
----------------------------------
1 | 3 | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |
1 | 5 | Extra | Columns | In | 1 |
```

Is there a way I can do this simply?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B']')` and drop extra columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B'], how='inner').drop('2', axis=1)
```

**`how='inner'` is default**. Just put it there for your understanding of how `df.merge` works.

As @piRSquared suggested, you can do:

```
df1.merge(df2[['A', 'B']], how='inner')
```

Comment: I'd do `df1.merge(df2[['A', 'B']], how='inner')`

Comment: That gets you your `on` and `drop` in one step.

Comment: @piRSquared Updated my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think `how='inner'` works in this case to get the desired dataframe, but technically, the OP's interest would seem to require `how='left'` so that all the data in the left dataframe is retained. `inner` will drop anything in the first dataframe (the left one) that does not have a match in the second (right) dataframe.

Comment: @SavageHenry Actually no. If you look at OP's expected output. It clearly looks like an `inner` join.